# Tinymce 5: Custom toolbar button to execute predefined plugin

Tags: tinymce-5

i'd like to show the template plugin popup window manually from a custom toolbar button but it doesnt seem to work if i execute the command "mceInsertTemplate".

It works i.e. when executing some default commands like "Bold" or similar.

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: '.tinymce',
  language: 'de',
  statusbar: false,
  plugins: "table lists autoresize template",
  menubar: "",
  toolbar: "bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist | table | removeformat undo redo | template | myCustomToolbarButton | ",
  templates: [
    {title: 'Some title 1', description: 'Some desc 1', content: 'My content'},
    {title: 'Some title 2', description: 'Some desc 2', url: 'development.html'}
    ],

  setup: (editor) => {
    editor.ui.registry.addButton('myCustomToolbarButton', {
      text: 'My Custom Button',
      onAction: function (_) {
        editor.execCommand('mceInsertTemplate');
        }
      })
    }

  });
```

Maybe someone can point me to the right direction.

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Comment: As the template plugin already has its own toolbar why would you not just use that toolbar button?

Comment: Because the built-in template icon is too unintuitive. I'd like to define my own text button.